# Shell Script: execute & repeat a python program that needs extra input

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have to run this python command: `python manage.py rebuild_index` at a certain time and rerun again. Therefore, I am trying the shell script to run it. However, when run this python command, I have to choose `y` to continue.

[image]

my **run_rebuild.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py rebuild_index
```

Moreover, how can I let the `run_rebuild.sh` rerun again after every 60 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) for this:

```
yes | python /manage.py rebuild_index
```

One way to run your script every minute:

```
while yes | python /manage.py rebuild_index; do
  sleep 60
done
```

The above will run your script every 60 second until it fails.

Comment: thank you,,this can work for "y",,and how can I keep run this sh every minute? thank you

Comment: your answer is mostly correct ,,but I have to remove "/" ,so I can run it:  /manage.py ---> manage.py  ,,thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) (redirects the output from `echo` to `python`'s `stdin`):

```
echo "y" | python manage.py rebuild_index
```

Comment: thank you,,this can work for "y",,and how can I keep run this sh every minute?

Comment: That's another question, quite possibly asked before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo "y"` (as @LogicStuff said) and `cron` jobs to accomplish this.

Create a script file (let's say `your_script.sh`) and add your command to it

```
echo "y" | python manage.py rebuild_index
```

To use `cron` you can use the following steps:-

```
crontab -e
```

This will open up the cronjob file in your default editor, add the following line to the file

```
* * * * * sh /path/to/your_script.sh
```